# Group looped entries into blocks and wrap in markup every x number of loops

Tags: forloop

I am trying to loop through all the entries in a section and "group" them into items which are in blocks of 9 then wrap them with some html markup so there will be the following code:

```
{% set selectedWork = craft.entries.section('selectedWork') %}

<div class="panel panel--1">
  <article class="img-grid">

    {% for item in selectedWork %}
    <section class="img-grid__item">
      {{ item.title }}
    </section>
    {% endfor %}

  </article>
</div><!-- END .panel -->
```

The outer `<div class="panel panel-1">` and `<article>` tags need to wrap round the first 9 items then then next 9 etc. etc. Also the panel--1 needs to increment so that each panel goes in order so `panel--1` holds 1-9 items then `panel--2` holds 9-18 items etc. Is this possible using some kind of array splice or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The array slice something you are looking for is Twig's [`batch`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html) filter. Here's how you'd set up the groups and use [`loop.index`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) to generate the class name.

```
{# Use the `find()` method to return an array of EntryModels #}
{% set selectedWork = craft.entries.section('selectedWork').find() %}

{# Group entries using the `batch` filter #}
{% set selectedWorkGrouped = selectedWork|batch(9) %}

{% for group in selectedWorkGrouped %}

    {# Set class using the loop index from outer loop #}
    {% set panelClass = 'panel--' ~ loop.index %}

    <div class="panel {{ panelClass }}">

        {% for entry in group %}
            <section class="img-grid__item">
                {{ entry.title }}
            </section>
        {% endfor %}

    </div

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Wow I didn't know about the batch filter, this solution worked like a charm. Thank you very much.